# Invalid multibyte sequence when requiring rest-open-uri

Tags: ruby

I uninstalled Ruby 1.9.3 and installed Ruby 2.0, went and installed the `rest-open-uri` gem since one of the scripts that I wrote used that gem, but this error occurs when I try to run it

> E:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require': E:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rest-open-uri-1.0.0/lib/rest-open-uri.rb:413: invalid multibyte escape: /[\r\n\t !#-[]-~\x80-\xff]+|(\[\x00-\x7f])/ (SyntaxError)

Why does this happen? I'm not entirely sure if it's due to me using a newer version of Ruby. The gem was released in 2006 so it is probably outdated and no longer supported.

Other scripts that I have use `RestClient`, which does not have this problem, so if the best solution is to just drop the outdated libraries and move to newer ones that is probably what I'll do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the differences between ruby 1.9 and ruby 2.0 is that the default encoding is now `utf-8`. To fix this issue you should edit the file E:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rest-open-uri-1.0.0/lib/rest-open-uri.rb, and add the first line:

```
# encoding: US-ASCII
```

see [here](http://techoverflow.net/blog/2013/12/29/solve-invalid-multibyte-escape-xfe-xff-in-ruby-vpim/) for more details